# Preloading a UIWebView, avoiding white screen flash

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm working on an app that has table navigation to eventually drill down to `UIWebView` that displays various information. However, the transition from the slickness of `UITableView` to the slow wonkiness of `UIWebView` is jarring for the user so I want to improve that experience however I can.

Specifically, the background of both the `tableViews` and `UIWebView` pages have black backgrounds, but when I open the `UIWebView` it flashes empty white for about a second (this is the case for both local and remote HTML files.) How can I (ideally) preload this process, or (at least) make the "flash" be all black rather than all white? I tried making the view / webView's background black but that didn't seem to help.

In my app right now, when a user selects a cell, the app just loads up the `UIWebView` subclass and pushes it on the navigation stack. The `UIWebView` subclass has an activity indicator that starts & stops animating on `WebViewDidStartLoad` and WebViewDidFinishLoad, which works fine, but it doesn't do anything to help the "white flash."

Comment: You say that the UIWebView has a black background: is that set in the HTML/CSS or is that actually set on the view itself? If the former then try [myWebView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor]];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tested it... I'm sending the two method that I have used...

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad]; //objWebView is the outlet of UIWebView
        [objWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color:black;\"></body></html>" baseURL:nil];

        //the more the delay the errors will be less so within 0.1-0.3 would be fine
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadURL:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; 
    }

-(void)loadURL:(id)sender{
    [objWebView stopLoading]; //added this line to stop the previous request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [objWebView loadRequest:req];
}
```

here I'm performing the request after 0.1 sec, other wise it will look white as in your case. Or you can give your delay time depending upon the time.. Cheers :)

Comment: Good news- this worked! In that it got rid of the white. Bad news, it's now giving an NSError, any ideas why? `Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x4baee10 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=about:blank, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=about:blank}` Despite the error, it's actually working normally, in that it actually does still load up the website, and doesn't flash white.

Comment: URL Loading System Error Codes
NSURLErrorCancelled = -999

NSURLErrorCancelled
Returned when an asynchronous load is canceled.
A Web Kit framework delegate will receive this error when it performs a cancel operation on a loading resource. Note that an NSURLConnection or NSURLDownload delegate will not receive this error if the download is canceled.

Comment: I'll look into it more, it's probably some unrelated issue with my own code. I gave you credit for answering the question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the NSURLErrorDomain only appears because the previous request is being cancelled. I think it would be first one..updating the answer..and it will work.. and then accept the answer.. :)

Comment: What I did was this: `if ([error code] != -999) { //show alert, etc. }` so it won't alert the user just in this case.

Comment: hmm that's just ignoring the error... but I have updated the code above and It won't come because of first request...I tested it on my test project and was giving the error -999 because of previous request. Yeah your idea will also work...

Comment: but if your original web page request is cancelled the for that case you will be ignoring your error and alert won't be shown any more...

Answer (score 9):

Try in your

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
       myWebView.hidden = YES;
```

Then in

```
    -(void)loadURL:(id)sender{  
        myWebView.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
[webView setHidden:YES];  
[webView setDelegate:self];
```

when creating my webView and making the request and then added this delegate method to handle completed requests:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView{  
    [webView setHidden:NO];  
}
```

Comment: Maybe set the setHidden:No in an own method and call it with performSelector afterDelay. The webViewDidFinishLoad is still to early on my iPad 3

Comment: I really think this should be the accepted answer, is clean and easy to understand. maybe it can be better using property notation: `webView.hidden = NO` and `webView.delegate = self`

Comment: This doesn't work, I have used the same approach and the black screen page still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully done it.
You have to create a view in Interface Builder first.
Then load the html to the webview using a initWithFrame in the init of your ViewController that contains the webview(this is where the magic happens):

```
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
```

Then simply load the webView into the view in viewWillAppear:

```
[viewWeb addSubview:webView];
```

This is really a question of interface designing, which is faster paint directly on the view or paint in a subview and then paint that subview in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem years ago, using the common method of hiding the UIWebView behind a UIImageView, then removing the UIImageView after a delay.

But it suddenly came back, I think on iOS 7.0.4. It was occurring on a brand new iPad Air, as well as an older iPad mini non-retina. After two days of hair-pulling, I finally found a work-around.

Let's say you have webview which is restricted to landscape orientation, initialized like this:

```
WebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];
```

And then you make it visible after pre-loading, with eg bringSubviewToFront or setHidden:NO on the webview (or alternatively with setHidden:YES or removeFromSuperview on the UIImageView). But instead of seamlessly switching the views, there's a flash and the background color blinks for about half a second.

The fix is to change the size of your webview, ever so slightly:

```
WebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024.01f, 768.0f)];
```

The problem and fix is highly reproducible. It works with a change as slight as the fourth decimal place (1024.0001f). At the fifth decimal place (1024.00001f), the flash returns. The value of the height (768.0f) didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score -2):

Or, instead of working around the problem, you could just set the background color of your webview to whatever background color you're using. Unless you're using an image of course.

Comment: Try loading a string of HTML that only has a transparent body before loading a network URL. I remember fixing this some way before, maybe this was it.

Comment: Background of the web view or the parent view does not affect the blanck screen.