# How to force UIWebView to load before transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview, uiviewanimationtransition

iOS 6.1

When a button is tapped, I want to perform a transition from an imageview to a webview.
The problem is that the very first time the webview loads, the page is white and the html page loads **after** the transition:

```
NepContainerView *containerInFrame = (NepContainerView *)[self view];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[UIView transitionWithView:containerInFrame
                      duration:DURATION_TRANS_PHOTO_DESC
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                        [containerInFrame addSubview:webView];
                        [sender setTitle:@" Photo "];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
```

How can I force the html page to be loaded **before** the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this [WebContentView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/WebContentView) library.

this library have one method named as

```
+ (void)preloadContent:(NSString *)content;
```

You can use this method to preload the content so that it will render fast.

hope it helps.

Here is the useful link that will help you

[Preloading a UIWebView, avoiding white screen flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987074/preloading-a-uiwebview-avoiding-white-screen-flash)

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve the same result without having to use an external library?

Comment: the link i have suggested will also work and the @Developer answer also you can try

Comment: The solution indicated in the link sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, so I'm not sure it can be considered a solution, at least for my case.

Comment: Having said that, it surely mitigates the problem. If you add the link as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate of UIWebView and when 
`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;` 
will called then call your method for transition

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerInFrame
                      duration:DURATION_TRANS_PHOTO_DESC
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                        [containerInFrame addSubview:webView];
                        [sender setTitle:@" Photo "];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
```

Comment: It sounds like a good plan, but somehow I'm struggling to set the delegate. In my header file I added:

@interface PhotoNepVC : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>

After creating the webview:

        webView.delegate = self;

but the delegate is not called. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think this solution will work. The delegate works only if I add the webView to the container, which is something that should be done during the animation. Even adding a hidden webView to the container and making it visible with the animation, it doesn't work.

Comment: you are doing  [containerInFrame addSubview:webView]; do it when you are allocating UIWebView and handle is using visibility property.

Comment: As I said, I tried to use the visibility property and it still loads the page as blank to start with. Moreover, I don't want to create a connection between the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate and the transition, because that webview is supposed to load other content that is not supposed to trigger any transition.