# Preloading mathjax into a collection iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collections, rendering, mathjax

(Please excuse the amount of text)

I'm trying to render a bunch of math questions in an app. Say there's 30 questions, and each question has about 7-8 fields (instructions, question, answer choices, and review).

I am able to do this successfully when I load them into containers with MathJax rendering (I also use a callback in the JS to make sure the content is loaded before being viewed).

The thing is, the process takes a few seconds each time, and I'd like to preload the entire set of questions, and the views, so that after the initial load, question loading will be instantaneous.

I think using a collection would be the best way to do this, and I've been trying two methods with no luck:

- load the collection with all the content as cells/items, then jump to the cell (I was facing the issue that only the viewed cell would load, and then I figured if they did all load, I would face the issue that I am facing now with the next option)
- load all the content into an invisible subview, then load the subview into a cell when it is selected (may offer more control over how things are loaded)

In either case, I run into the same issue (and this even happened in the initial one-by-one loading with multiple containers, where if I jumped around too quickly, the app would crash).

- When loading a bunch of subviews, each with Mathjax, the app gets overwhelmed and crashes (I believe due to memory or cpu, it says "lost connection to iPad"). This doesn't seem to happen if there is a lot of Mathjax within one view. I think it's because the processes don't wait for each other to finish before beginning, and the app can't handle running multiple Mathjax rendering at the same time.

I think a possible solution is to make sure that the loop that loads the view does not reloop until the Mathjax is done rendering, but cannot figure out a way to make the loop wait (once it initiates the loading it keeps incrementing).

Hopefully someone can provide a good idea for:

- how to structure the preloading mechanism in general

or

- how to specifically make the loop wait for the view to render before relooping (I have a process that recognizes when the Mathjax has been fully rendered, but I can't figure out how to make the loop wait for it. This process is currently used to simply unhide the view once it's done).

  ```
  for var i = 0; i < objectsKeyValues.count; i++ {

      let iInput:String = cDParentVC.string1 + cDContentAbstraction.objectsKeyValues[i]["instructions"]! + cDParentVC.string2
      let qInput:String = cDParentVC.string1 + cDContentAbstraction.objectsKeyValues[i]["question"]! + cDParentVC.string2
      ... for a few more of these


      let iView = WKWebView.init(frame: CGRectMake(5,5,300,35), configuration: config)
      ...same


      iView.loadHTMLString(iInput, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
      ..same

      viewDictArray.append(["iView":iView,"qView":qView,"a1View":a1View,"a2View":a2View,"a3View":a3View,"a4View":a4View,"a5View":a5View,"rView":rView,"pView":pView])

      cDLargeContent.invisiView.addSubview(viewDictArray[i]["iView"]!)
      ...same

  }
  ```

I suspect NSOperations or GCD could also provide the necessary controls, but I am pretty green with programming and haven't been able to implement those concepts successfully, let alone verify if they would solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try the approach at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25642872/1587329? and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437792/how-to-force-uiwebview-to-load-before-transition?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it would work in a viewDidLoad setting.. the set of questions is loaded dynamically based on selection from another table. I believe the issue is rendering the math overwhelms the system somehow. Do you have any advice on what debugging methods I should use to identify what exactly is going haywire?

Comment: Also, is it possible to cache or save something in a rendered form? So that the rendering work can be done at one point and then retrieved at another point (I believe its the rendering that takes up time and CPU).